# How to calculate this normal distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution

I have this mass of probability is proportional to $$exp[-\frac{\beta}{2}\parallel x-Hz\parallel^{2}-\frac{\alpha}{2}z^{t}C^{t}Cz]$$ and I have to calculate to its distribution but I don't know how, its distribution is $$\mathcal{N}((\alpha C^{t}C+\beta H^{t}H)^{-1}\beta H^{t} x,(\alpha C^{t}C+\beta H^{t}H)^{-1}.$$
$z$ and $x$ are vectors and $H$ and $C$ matrices,
Any idea?

Comment: should the $||x-Hz||$ be $||x-Hz||^2$? And are you familiar with completing the square for vectors?

Comment: Could you explain your notation a bit more. what is $z$ for instance?

Comment: For sure is squared but I don't know how to complete square for vectors. And x and  z are a vectors, C and H are matrixs.

Comment: matrices, not matrixs

Comment: Do you know matrix algebra? You should expand $\Vert x-Hz \Vert^2$ as$$(x-Hz)^\text{T}(x-Hz)$$